# copy only those rows whose string len is > 6 in b column  cell values

Tags: vba, excel

is it possible to copy only those rows which has string length more than 6 characters and paste them to a new sheet? The task is I have to remove all the unwanted characters in the rows. the range is 2 to 4000 something like that

I was using looping and mid function to do that which i found on google because I found only looping solution to that on google, because I only need numbers in each cell of B column and remove all other character except &,/, ,,. Then after cleaning up all ce
lls in B column I need to check the number of digits in each row of B column and if it contains more than 6 it should be copied to new sheet and it may contain blank cells too in between

```
 a       b           c 
6451    1234567   somevalue
4563    12345     somevalue
3245    123456789 somevalue
2345    1234      somevalue
```

Now I have to copy the 1 and 3 rd row but not the other rows as length of string is less than 7. I have to check only the B column and copy the entire row if it has more than 6 digits

Comment: You need to have better communication with your boss.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta I asked him hows that possible , He says many people did it, I have seen though he never done VBA and i cant argue with him without knowing the possibility right? if some one here let me know that i can talk to him on that!

Comment: You are likely to be able to do this with a working formula column, ie use a formula to extract only the digits, then autofilter the results that are more than 6 characters long. A data sample would help ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what your boss is trying to say (not very well, btw) about using variant arrays, etc. instead of worksheets is to keep it in VBA. Read in the data once and manipulate it within VBA instead of pasting and manipulating data on a worksheet to get the desired result. This of course extends to anything outside of making calls to Excel, not just variant arrays. Perhaps you are often looping through cells one by one and he is trying to say he'd prefer if you dumped a range into a variant array and worked on it inside of VBA instead.

Of course, the best method depends on the task on hand, in my opinion.

As for your row question, it's a little unclear what you're trying to do (try to be careful how you use the words 'row' 'cell' and 'column'). A row cannot have a 'string length' so I am assuming you mean cell. Please confirm.

Comment: ok @issun I will try my own way to do it if its not optimized than I will ask for your suggestions Thanks so im just speding time to learn concepts on variants! Im inspired by your explaination! THanks

Comment: Thanks and good luck! The best thing to know about v. arrays is that the big difference between them and arrays of other types is you can dump an entire range of cells into a varray in 1 step. You can't do that with other types of arrays. Doing work on elements of a varray  is light years faster than doing a for each loop through each cell which is why it's often used in Excel VBA. My suggestion is play around with dumping ranges into varrays, then use the stop keyword or break points to go into VBE, and look at the varray details in the locals window to see how the data ended up in the array.

Comment: @isuun could you please help with my question I posted in vba Please we will delete entirerow but how to delete an item in variant ? I dont find any variant info on google I find arrays could you please help me with these?

Comment: Deleting items in arrays is never easy to do and not really practical. I added an answer to your other q. I hope it helps.